# PPTP VPN Error 807 through Portable Wi-Fi hotspot

Tags: nexus-one, vpn, wifi-tethering

Recently I noticed when my laptop (Windows 8) connects to the Internet through Android Portable Wi-Fi hotspot (Nexus One running stock 2.3), it can't connect to my company's PPTP VPN (resulting a 807 error). But if my laptop connects through USB tethering, it connects to the VPN just fine. Has any one experienced similar issues?